# wrong field INTO OUTFILE mysql due to " string

Tags: php, mysql, string, csv

I'm trying to export data from database using mysql, and found out the field result was wrong

Here's my database structure :

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subgroup       | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_desc      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| item_code      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

database content :

```
+-------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| id    | subgroup | item_desc             | item_code       |
+-------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| 10250 | FAN      | KIPAS ANGIN G-TEK 30" | PSTS10000000008 |
+-------+----------+-----------------------+-----------------+
```

MYSQL query :

```
if (isset($_GET['download_item_csv'])) {

    $file_name = uniqid();
    $file_name .= '-item.csv';

    mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT 'Subgroup','Item Description','Item Code' UNION ALL SELECT subgroup,item_desc,item_code
    FROM item_master
    INTO OUTFILE 'D:/BULUS/htdocs/project/bulus/admin/tmp/$file_name'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");

    header('Content-type: text/csv');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name.'');
    readfile('tmp/'.$file_name.'');
    unlink('tmp/'.$file_name.'');
    exit();

}
```

my current .csv file outputs :

[image: current .csv result]

expected .csv file output :

[image: expected .csv file output]

already tried several method including string escape theroy, but still doesn't work

Comment: The result unfortunately also depends on the software that you used to import the csv.

Comment: @Shadow would you please be more specific ? do you mean the method and software of importing the data will affect the export / output file ?

Comment: Can you show the raw cvs output?

Comment: @danblack this is the raw csv output : 
"FAN","KIPAS ANGIN G-TEK 30\"","PSTS10000000008"

Comment: So the raw output is correct. Its just what you are using to read the CVS doesn't understand the \ escaping of "

Comment: @owf almost each software that can import a csv file has its own way to handle edge cases, escape characters. You need to understand how your target software handles these cases and tailor your output to match those requirements. Unfortunately, it may happen that select into outfile cannot produce the output that your target software requires.

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer from here :

https://www.facebook.com/groups/2322832835/?multi_permalinks=10157945752997836&comment_id=10157945863812836&notif_id=1582274650091392&notif_t=feedback_reaction_generic
credits to : Alex Torres

```
mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT 'Subgroup','Item Description','Item Code' UNION ALL SELECT subgroup,item_desc,item_code
FROM item_master
INTO OUTFILE 'D:/BULUS/htdocs/project/bulus/admin/tmp/$file_name'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '\"'
ESCAPED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'");
```

it works perfectly to avoid quotes (") case